# My telerik mvc tabstrip does not work

Tags: telerik-mvc

I have a TabStrip in a UserControl that is shown in a Telerik window. This window is shown as a result of the addition of one record in a Telerik grid, but i cant change the tabs clicking on it.

I could try to make it work with TabStrip events and some javascript but this stuff is done in the control (I'm sure in the Telerik example they do nothing to make it work).

I have added the `<%: Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true)) %>` to load all javascript needed, I suppose it must be something like I must add some script but I have no idea. I have created my project from Telerik Mvc Project Addin for VS 2010 so it put all what i need in the project already.

Some help would be great.

I will copy here the TabStrip code, maybe it is something in the code, but I'm just copying and pasting the same TabStrip from the example.

```
<%
    Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
        .Name("TabStrip")
        .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add().Text("Item 1")
                 .Content(() =>
                 {%>
<p>
    Content</p>
<%});
            items.Add().Text("Item 2")
                 .Content(() =>
                 {%>
<p>
    Content</p>
<%});
        })
        .SelectedIndex(0)
        .Render();
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have hit [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-troubleshooting.html#LoadOnDemand) problem. The solution is to include the JavaScript files [required](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-required-javascript-files.html) by the TabStrip.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.Telerik().TabStrip().Name("TabStrip").Items(items =>
{
    items.Add().Text("First").Content(@<p>First Page</p>);
    items.Add().Text("Second").Content(@<p>Second Page</p>);

}).SelectedIndex(0)
```

The above code worked for me. You can replace `@` by `<%=  %>`..